# Ｒ言語で展開されている2次元データを表にする

Tags: r

以下のように、展開されている２次元データを元に戻す処理をしたいのですが、R言語でどう書けばよいでしょうか？

data.csv
X1 Y1 値
X1 Y2 値
X2 Y1 値
X2 Y2 値

↓

output.csv
　　Y1　Y2
X1　値　値
X2　値　値

列ごとにlevels()で取得したリストを、空配列のnameに入れておいて、あとからもう一度1行ずつ読み込んでnameでアクセスして目的の場所に入れなおそうとしてみたのですがうまくいきませんでした。
XやYがカテゴリカルデータなのですが、その名前に特殊記号（[や/）が含まれているからかもしれないと思っています。

スマートな方法はありませんでしょうか…。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: CSV ファイルを data frame(`df`) に読み込んで、`t <- xtabs(df[,3] ~ df[,1] + df[,2])` として `write.csv(t, file="output.csv", quote=F)` でしょうかね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV ファイルを data frame(df) に読み込んで、t <- xtabs(df[,3] ~ df[,1] + df[,2]) として write.csv(t, file="output.csv", quote=F)

で、求めていた操作ができました！
xtabsの扱いについて今後勉強したいと思います。ありがとうございました。